# Additional/Custom properties for each cell in a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, cell

I have a DataTable, that I show in DGV. I'd like to have couple more properties for each cell in addition to Value. Let's say, I want to specify if the Value is old/new, correct/incorrect, red/blue, etc.
How should I go about this?

Comment: Make your value an object with properties.Probably you need to handle the format/parse event,to select the display value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataGridViewCell.Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tag) property can store any object associated with the value displayed by this cell

You can address it like this:

```
      public class CellProperties { 
        public Boolean Correct { get; } 
        public Boolean Changed { get; } 
        public CellProperties(Boolean correct, Boolean changed) 
        { 
            Correct = correct; Changed = changed; 
        } 
    } 
CellProperties props = this.dataCOMPGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Tag 
                           as CellProperties;
if(props.Correct)
...
```

Comment: Let's say I created class: 
`        public class CellProperties
        {
            public Boolean Correct { get; }
            public Boolean Changed { get; }

            public CellProperties(Boolean correct, Boolean changed)
            {
                Correct = correct;
                Changed = changed;
            
            }
        
        }
`
and then:
`
this.dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Tag = new CellProperties(true, false);
`
How would I address it?
Like:
`this.dataCOMPGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Tag.Correct`